# Rebind org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe to C-c C-c

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

In org mode, i can not use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
I have try to rebind it in my .emacs

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe)
```

I have also try

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
    (define (kbd "C-c C-c") 'org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe))
```

But when i hit the keys in a code block in org mode, nothing (the keybind is not bind to anything).

When i hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe, everything works fine.

Thank you :)

EDIT:
All the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> are unbind in org-mode I simply would like to rebind it to its original function.

Comment: What does Emacs say (both in org mode and in general) when you use `C-h k C-c C-c`?

Comment: Nothing because it is not assigned to anything.

Comment: @hanoo By default it should it assigned to `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` in org mode buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in my .emacs I had

```
(use-package ace-jump-mode
   :ensure t
   :defer t
   :bind* (("C-c SPC" . ace-jump-mode)
           ("C-c C-c SPC" . ace-jump-mode-pop-mark))
   :config (ace-jump-mode-enable-mark-sync))
```

The "C-c C-c" default behaviour was overridden by "C-c C-c SPC". I changed it and the default behaviour Is BACK :D.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would like to correct my mistake in my earlier answer (now deleted).

> <s>*When the point is in the source blocks, the org-src-mode-map is active.*</s>

Actually the `org-src-mode-map` is active in the temporary buffer that pops up after you hit `C-c '` (bound to `org-edit-special`) when the point is in a source block like below.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(message "Hi")
#+END_SRC
```

So please disregard my earlier answer.

---

### Tested solution

The solution that might work for your case is to advise the `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` function. This is the function bound to `C-c C-c` by default in `org-mode-map`.

The below advice will made the `org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe` if the point is in an org source block when you hit `C-c C-c`. Otherwise, the `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` function will run as usual.

```el
(defun my/advice-org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c (&rest args)
  "Run `org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe' if point is in an org source block."
  (let ((do-not-run-orig-fn (org-in-src-block-p)))
    (when do-not-run-orig-fn
      (call-interactively #'org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe))
    do-not-run-orig-fn))
(advice-add 'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c :before-until #'my/advice-org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

*Above solution is tested using `emacs -Q` (version 25.0.94) and latest build of org from its [git master](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/log/).*

---

### Warning!

By doing this, you will be overriding the default behavior of `C-c C-c` in source blocks. Below is a snippet from the documentation we get on doing `C-h f org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`:

> - If the cursor is on a code block, evaluate it.  The variable
>     ‘org-confirm-babel-evaluate’ can be used to control prompting
>     before code block evaluation, by default every code block
>     evaluation requires confirmation.  Code block evaluation can be
>     inhibited by setting ‘org-babel-no-eval-on-ctrl-c-ctrl-c’.

Comment: I finally did find the problem/solution, give you +1 for the help :)